# starting xdebug inside code?

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I know these ways of starting Xdebug:

`?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=name` in url

`xdebug.remote_autostart=On` in php.ini

`-dxdebug.remote_autostart=On` as parameter to the PHP binary call

but I do not know how to start xdebug inside code, is there any function like `xdebug_start()` and `xdebug_stop()` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to start the debugging somewhere else in your PHP code than at the start, you need to set `xdebug.remote_mode=jit`in `php.ini`. Then when you call `xdebug_break` the debugging session will start.

Answer (score 7):

```
xdebug_enable()
xdebug_disable()
```

> void xdebug_enable() Enables stack traces
>
> void xdebug_disable() Disables stack traces

http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions

Also from the manual:`xdebug_start_code_coverage`, `xdebug_get_code_coverage`

```
<?php
    xdebug_start_code_coverage();

    function a($a) {
        echo $a * 2.5;
    }

    function b($count) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            a($i + 0.17);
        }
    }

    b(6);
    b(10);

    var_dump(xdebug_get_code_coverage());
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

It's an ini setting so you can do:

```
ini_set('xdebug.profiler_enable', 1);
```

Comment: This ini_set doesn't work: "This setting can not be set in your script with ini_set()" from http://www.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#profiler_enable